# PyQt5 QtSerialPort Error QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket specified

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtserialport

I'm trying to use QtSerialPort for a PyQt5 project but haven't found the magic.  Right now the code seems to be opening the port but I'm getting "QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket specified" error whenever I try to write to the port.  Here's the latest code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo

class QtSerialTest():

    def __init__(self):
        super(QtSerialTest, self).__init__()

        self.serinfo = QSerialPortInfo()
        p = self.serinfo.availablePorts()
        for pport in p:
            print(pport.portName())

        portname = p[0].portName()
        self.ser = QSerialPort(portname)
        self.ser.setBaudRate(9600)
        print(self.ser.isOpen())
        self.ser.setOpenMode(QSerialPort.ReadWrite)
        print(self.ser.isOpen()) 

        self.ser.writeData(b'Test')

if __name__=='__main__':
    ser = QtSerialTest()
```

The output from this code on my machine is:

```
ttyUSB0
ttyUSB1
ttyUSB2
ttyUSB3
ttyUSB4
ttyUSB5
ttyUSB6
ttyUSB7
False
True
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket specified
```

Any idea what is causing the QSocketNotifier error, or how to troubleshoot it?  If you run this code do you get the same error?

Comment: What Qt version is this with?

Comment: Looks like Qt5.6.0, using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This occurs with Qt 5.14 using C++ QWebsockets as well. I made a server and flooded it with 20k 1mb messages. Rather than signalling me with any errors, it just hangs and I see the "QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket specified" message on the command line. The same code runs fine with 5k messages.